# LINQ grouping - get other, not grouped properties

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, group-by

I have little problem with my LINQ query (nHibernate)

I need to have count of objects *znak* with equal property *Symbol*

My query:

```
            var tmp = (from znak in sesja.Query<Znak>()
                       group znak by znak.Symbol into r
                       select new { Name= r.Key.Name, SUM= r.Count() });
```

This query works, but I need to make object contains other properties of *znak* class.

In this case: `select new { Name= r.Key.Name, SUM= r.Count() });` i can make new objects only from r.Key, (*Symbol* property). But I need other properties in my *new* object.

Is it possible ?

Comment: What "other properties" do you want?

Comment: Reed, in Znak Class I Have properties like Symbol (grouping property), and some more like Size, Name etc... But in my new item i cant get other than Symbol properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using lambda Linq syntax:

```
var items = sesja.Query<Znak().AsEnumerable();

var newList = items.GroupBy(x=>x.Symbol).Select(
       x=> new { Name=x.Key.Name, Count = x.Count(), Items = x.ToList() });
```

read more about Linq syntax [LINQ: Dot Notation vs Query Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630045/linq-dot-notation-vs-query-expression)

I think that `lambda syntax` is more readable and looks much cleaner in code because it's more c# style not sql style.

Of course there will be no difference in IL code, always you can install tools like resharper, they can convert lambda syntax to sql-like syntax.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Expression of type CE.Klasy.Znak cannot be used for parameter of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CE.Klasy.Znak] of method System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CE.Klasy.Znak] ToList[Znak](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CE.Klasy.Znak])”."}      Error shows on both answers. I tried with Items = x.ToList() and Items = x.ToList()<Znak>

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
var tmp = (from znak in sesja.Query<Znak>()
           group znak by znak.Symbol into r
           select new { Name= r.Key.Name, SUM= r.Count(), Items = r.ToList() });
```

`Items` property will contain actual objects in the group.

Comment: Worth noting that naming a `Count()` property `SUM` is confusing.  I know it's the OP's issue, but it's worth correcting.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Expression of type CE.Klasy.Znak cannot be used for parameter of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CE.Klasy.Znak] of method System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CE.Klasy.Znak] ToList[Znak](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CE.Klasy.Znak])”."} Error shows on both answers. I tried with Items = x.ToList() and Items = x.ToList()<Znak>   Any Ideas ?

Comment: @iskrzycki Try this: instead of `sesja.Query<Znak>()`, do `sesja.Query<Znak>().AsEnumerable()`. This might explain the behavior:  [Expression of type 'MyEnum' cannot be used for parameter of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651624/expression-of-type-myenum-cannot-be-used-for-parameter-of-type)

Comment: @AndreiTanas 'Better', but... **"Enumeration yielded no results"** if it's important, i'm using Nhivernate 3.1 with Fluent Nhibernate